# Como recuperar código fonte HTML bi Firefox via Addon/Complemento?

Tags: javascript, firefox, plugin

Estou escrevendo um complemento ("addon") para o Firefox. Preciso obter o código-fonte do HTML aberto na aba atual do Firefox e exibir em um `alert`, usando JavaScript.

Tentei usar `alert(document.documentElement.outerHTML)`, mas apenas mostra o código abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma sugestão ?

Comment: Assim? `alert(document.documentElement.outerHTML);`

Comment: @GabrielSantos, eu tentei dessa forma, mais em todas as páginas ele mostra o mesmo código, veja o print: http://prntscr.com/3ph5la  pq será ? tem algum bloqueio no firefox ?

Comment: Você quer o código fonte original? (tipo, o que o servidor enviou via HTTP, desconsiderando quaisquer alterações na página feitas via JavaScript por exemplo) Ou o conteúdo atual do DOM? E esse código JavaScript está na própria página, ou em outro lugar? (extensão do navegador, bookmarklet...)

Comment: @mgibsonbr, quero ver o código fonte original da página atual aberta na aba. Por exemplo, ta aberto lá globo.com, quero ver o código fonte dessa página. Esse código java script eu coloquei em um botão na barra de tarefas do FIREFOX.

Comment: Por que você não usa CTRL+U? O código raramente vai caber em um `alert`.

Comment: @bfavaretto, não tem problema não caber em um ALERT, pode ser em um console.log, depois eu vou colocar o código em uma variável, entende ? o ALERT foi apenas como exemplo.

Comment: Como este `alert` vai ser mostrado? Ele vai aparecer quando você clicar num botão, como em http://jsfiddle.net/brandizzi/sQ498/? Ele vai ser sempre executado, como em http://jsfiddle.net/brandizzi/GfRDZ/? Ele está num bookmarklet? Em todos estes cenários, a solução do @GabrielSantos funcionou aqui. Mostre-nos o código que você **já** tem e não está funcionando.

Comment: Aliás, aqui cabe outra pergunta: o que você quer fazer com o código-fonte posto numa variável? Por que você quer recuperá-lo todo? Talvez haja maneiras melhores de fazer o que você quer.

Comment: @brandizzi, realmente desse jeito seu deu certo acessando a página pelo firefox. No meu caso eu criei um botão na barra de ferramentas do firefox escrito "Exibir Código". Quando clico nesse botão deve exibir o código entendeu ? Criei uma extensão pra isso...

Comment: @brandizzi, pelo que entendi aqui, parece que ele não pega só o código do html e sim até da barra de ferramentas pelo fato do botão estar lá, entende ? pelo menos parece que é isso....

Comment: @brandizzi, é cara, é isso mesmo...como meu botão fica na barra de tarefas e eu clico para exibir o código, ele ta pegando os códigos das ABAS e não da pagina HTML é mole ?

Comment: Então o código está numa extensão/complemento/addon, né? Qual é a versão do seu Firefox?

Comment: Isso mesmo @brandizzi, está em um addon/complemento, minha versão é a 29.0.1, acredito que seja a última versão....

Comment: Aaaaaaaagora faz sentido :) Rascunhei uma extensão aqui e acho que encontrei a resposta. Uma sugestão: edite a questão, para deixar claro que você está escrevendo JavaScript para um complemento, que não é um JavaScript em uma página HTML em si. Há um mundo de diferença entre complementos e páginas :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como você está escrevendo um complemento para o Firefox, você deve saber que o Firefox em si é um grande programa escrito em JavaScript e XUL (a linguagem de marcação esquisita dele, que serve, de certo modo, como um HTML com cara nativa e com muito mais componentes). Pois bem, quando você clica no botão da extensão, o documento atual é a própria janela do Firefox, logo ele exibirá o código-fonte XUL da janela.

Presumo que seu código JavaScript seja algo como o abaixo:

```
var seesource = {
  run : function(aEvent) {
    alert(document.documentElement.outerHTML);
  }
};
```

Felizmente, o escopo dos scripts conterá uma variável chamada `content`, que referenciará o conteúdo da tab atual. O segredo é pegar o `document` desta variável:

```
var seesource = {
  run : function(aEvent) {
    alert(content.document.documentElement.outerHTML);
  }
};
```

Veja o resultado

[image: alert() mostrando o código-fonte HTML de pudim.com.br]

Isto, porém, não vale se você estiver usando o [Addon SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK), a maneira mais moderna de desenvolver complementos. Neste caso, [a coisa será um pouco mais complicada](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8573135/287976) (em inglês) mas claramente não é seu caso.

- O código completo da extensão está no [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/brandizzi/seesource). Se quiser, baixe a [versão falha](https://bitbucket.org/brandizzi/seesource/downloads/seesource-0.1.xpi) ([revisão](https://bitbucket.org/brandizzi/seesource/src/815f547)) ou a [versão completa](https://bitbucket.org/brandizzi/seesource/downloads/seesource-0.2.xpi) ([revisão](https://bitbucket.org/brandizzi/seesource/src/86413c7)).

Comment: Caramba @brandizzi, perfeito a sua resposta, só faltava colocar esse bendito content kkkkkkkkk ....Obrigado amigo, vou editar a pergunta sim. Abraços!!!

Answer (score 1):

Se a página tiver o jQuery incluído, o seguinte funciona:

```
$.get(document.html, function(html) { alert(html); } );
```

Mas para funcionar em todas as páginas, o ideal é usar a versão em Javascript puro:

```
// No IE, só funciona a partir da versão 9

request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", document.url, true);

request.onload = function() {
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400){
    // Sucesso!
    html = request.responseText;
    alert(html);
  } else {
    alert("O servidor retornou um erro")
  }
};

request.onerror = function() {
  alert("Não foi possível conectar ao servidor");
};

request.send();
```

Pode copiar e colar no console em qualquer página para testar.

Dica: quando tiver dúvida em como fazer algo sem jQuery, consulte: *[You Might Not Need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)*

Comment: coloquei esse código no meu arquivo js, ele não faz nada...não aparece nenhuma tela nem nada rsrsrs...Você chegou a testar ele ?

Comment: @user7605 Sim aqui funcionou. Você tentou o segundo código? Dá alguma saída (erro) no console?

Comment: aparece isso no console: NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND:

Comment: veja: http://prntscr.com/3pld42

Comment: @user7605 Tinha testado no Chrome e funciona. Testei no Firefox agora e ela lança uma das mensagens de erro se tu tirar o comentário (`// Sucesso`).

Comment: não entendi @Andrey.....retira esse comentário ?

Comment: Tem um comentário no meio do código (`// Sucesso`) que faz o Firefox se perder, pois o código fica todo em uma linha no console. Retirá-lo resolveu o erro de compilação, mas ele está retornando erro do servidor.

Comment: Realmente @Andrey, da erro mesmo, tem mais alguma ideia ?

Comment: O certo seria `location.href`e não `document.url`